# Are Twitter Bootstrap themes interchangeable with Wordpress themes?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, themes

Are Twitter Bootstrap themes interchangeable with Wordpress themes? How do I install a Twitter Bootstrap theme onto my Wordpress website?

Answer (score 1):

No, Twitter Bootstrap is a framework used to make development time of websites faster and easier by starting you off with stylesheets for grids, buttons, tabs, etc.

The Twitter Bootstrap can be used to make a Wordpress theme, but it is not directly one.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, when you find something that says "bootstrap theme", what they really mean is, "premade template that uses bootstrap as a basis and has a lot of custom styling".

Actual themes are interchangable, though they are hard to find. The best example of interchangeable bootstrap themes is http://bootswatch.com